# Why the `Title` property wasn't updated after `Update` method launching?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

SharePoint 2013

Bunch of my code:

```
SPWebService webService = SPFarm.Local.Services[webServiceGuid] 
    as SPWebService;
SPWebApplication webApp = webService.WebApplications[webApplicationGuid];

// path is "http://sharepoint2013/sites/sandbox2" string
SPSite siteCollection = webApp.Sites.Add(path, "root", 
    "abcdef@gmail.com");

siteCollection.RootWeb.Title = "My some sites collection";
siteCollection.RootWeb.Update();
```

My site collection was created successfully, but when I open the http://sharepoint2013/sites/sandbox2 page then I don't see updated value of the `Title`. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a problem if your SP has few languages installed. Try something like:

```
SPWebService webService = SPFarm.Local.Services[webServiceGuid]
    as SPWebService;
SPWebApplication webApp = webService.WebApplications[webApplicationGuid];

SPSite siteCollection = webApp.Sites.Add(ObjectPath, "root", "abcdef@gmail.com");

SPUserResource userResource = siteCollection.RootWeb.TitleResource;

foreach(CultureInfo culture in siteCollection.RootWeb.SupportedUICultures)
    userResource.SetValueForUICulture(culture, "My some sites collection");

siteCollection.RootWeb.Update();
```